# prime faces dialog is not working in my code

Tags: jsf, primefaces

in the below code I'm trying to get dialog box but its not showing,
here i used  JSF Facelets.

here i shared the full code that i have written in page

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="../template/CommonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="rightcontent">
            <div id="c1">
                <h:form>
                    <div id="password">
                        <p:commandButton value="reset" onclick="PF('dlg').show();"
                            title="Reset password" immediate="true">
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Reset password" widgetVar="dlg"
                            width="500px" resizable="true">

                            <h:panelGrid id="resetPanel" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                                <h:outputText value="newpassword" />
                                <h:inputSecret id="newpassword"
                                    value="#{custEditBean.newPassword}" required="true"></h:inputSecret>
                                <h:outputText value="Confirm password" />
                                <h:inputSecret id="confirm" value="#{custEditBean.password}"
                                    required="true"></h:inputSecret>

                                <p:commandButton value="RESET"
                                    actionListener="#custEditBean.changePassword()}" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:dialog>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

here i used JSF Facelets templets.

Comment: @kamwo: problem is just right there in the command button which should open the dialog. No need to clutter the question with more irrelevant code than already shown. OP just didn't have any basic HTML knowledge before diving into JSF and neglected to exactly follow the examples on PrimeFaces showcase.

Comment: yes, i gone through same example as in prime faces showcase, but when put same code in the JSF facelets its not showing dialog box.

Comment: No Shashi, the button which opens the dialog is absolutely not the same as on PrimeFaces showcase.

Comment: It's strange. Try putting the form and its content in a page with no template at all, just a typical JSF page, and tell us if the issue persists.

Comment: I don't see a reason for setting `immediate="true"` to your `p:commandButton` - if all you need from this button is to display the dialog using JavaScript, you could remove that attribute and just set `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

`h:inputSecret` and `p:commandButton` inside dialog has typos, its `value` and `actionListener` lacks first `{` character. I mean:

```
value="#custEditBean.password}"
```

instead

```
value="#{custEditBean.password}"
```

And the same for the button. Maybe this errors won't render your dialog.